# Abnormal Behavior with RadioButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I am using `RadioButton` in my layout. Where i have provided background to the `RadioButton`. Below is the code

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_spain"
        android:id="@+id/am_rb_spain" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_germany"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:id="@+id/am_rb_german" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:background="@drawable/rb_english"
        android:id="@+id/am_rb_english" />

</RadioGroup>
```

`RadioButton` background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spain" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spain_pressed" /> //pressed image is Large in size
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spain" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I have saved the selection in `TinyDB` so that app will remember my selection whenever i open my app. But whenever i open my app the default selected RadioButton background Appears Large. 
I have taken all the images of same size in drawable's with same padding.

First flag is Default selected here. But it appear to be slightly large in size

[image: First flag is Default selected here]

Now i have pressed 2nd flag. But first flag is not coming to its normal state.

[image: Now i have selected 2nd flag]

Comment: you might have misplaced the larger resolution image in smaller resolution folder, can you check it once

Comment: i have checked all the folder's from mdpi - xxxhdpi, everything fine in drawable's

Comment: every time you open your app, is that the only flag that appears large ?

Comment: no which ever is selected. If i select 2nd flag & reopen my app then the 2nd flag will behave like 1st one.

Comment: is ic_spain_pressed larger than ic_spain ??

Comment: yes, ic_flag_pressed is larger than ic_flag

Comment: if you are using larger ic_flag_pressed than it will be visible larger than unchecked flags. You should use same sizes for all six flags checked and unchecked.

Comment: @AnkiiRawat Rawat He wants the selected Flag to look larger, it is working fine but after selecting another flag the previously selected flag is not going to previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `android:button="@null"` to `android:button="@drawable/rb_germany"` and remove background from each RadioButton. It will run fine.

Your updated RadioButton should be like:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/rb_spain"
    android:id="@+id/am_rb_spain" />
```